# py2neo recursive matching

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo, neo4j-driver

I'm playing with py2neo and now the I'm looking for the most convenient manner to find all children of a specific node using recursion.

What I'm looking for is the following idea:

```cypher
MATCH (:LabelA {id:"C"})-[:to*]->(m:LabelA) RETURN n;
```

This is what it would look like in cypher. I know this query can be run with graph.run() and by passing this query. But I was wondering if somebody knows if it is possible using the graph.match() code?

Finding the first node is possible with:

```python
sNode = graph.nodes.match(id="C").first()
firstNode = graph.match((sNode, ), r_type="to")
```

and I'm hoping there is a construct such as (I tried this and this does not work :) ):

```python
sNode = graph.nodes.match(id="C").first()
nodesFound = graph.match((sNode, ), r_type="to*")
#do something with nodesFound
```

that would return all recursively found nodes in a list or so.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with the matchers. You'll have to use Cypher.